# How do I find a research topic without the guidance of a professor?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, research-process, graduate-school, professorship

I have been out of uni for quite some time now, but I would like to apply for UK (!) PhDs (so not the MA including US-PhDs). I am in the Humanities and I know the general topic within my field which I would like to focus on.

However, I am not sure what would make a good research question and even less sure how to find one. Any advice? How will I know? I am worried I will propose something ridiculous that will make me look immature, but I don't want to squander my chances with potential supervisors by looking so clueless.

Comment: Find a question that excites you because you don't know how to answer it (yet). Read the literature to see if anyone else has answered it, and if not, whether anyone else would care. Repeat as necessary.